# warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] }

Tags: c

c programming

code:

```
struct battleship makeShip (int size, int pos)
{
    int i, j;
    int* body;
    body = (int*) malloc (size * sizeof(int));
    for (i = pos; i < (pos + size); i++){
        for (j=0; j < size; j++){
            body[j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

not sure what is causing the error if i try and add a return 0; i get:

error: returning 'int' from a function with incompatible result
      type 'struct battleship'
    return 0;

Comment: You can't have different return type. If the function type is int  then only you can have return int. If you use other type it will complain.

Comment: there is no "struct battleship" variables even defined in your function, so not sure why you'd want to return one

Answer (score 0):

You would have to return a battleship structure.

If you don't need to return anything, just change:

```
struct battleship
```

with:

```
void
```

Meaning the function returns nothing.

Considering you allocate some memory here for something, you probably want to return the address of body, which is a pointer to int type.
In this case, your function should start with:

```
int * makeShip(int size, int pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct battleship makeShip (int size, int pos)
{
    int i, j;
    int* body;
    body = (int*) malloc (size * sizeof(int));
    for (i = pos; i < (pos + size); i++){
        for (j=0; j < size; j++){
            body[j] = 1;
        }
    }
    struct battleship ship;
    ship.body = body;
    ship.size = size;
    ship.pos = pos;
    return ship;
```

}